# Go's gofmt and diff/VCS issues?

Tags: version-control, diff, go

I've got a question about Go's *gofmt* tool, which formats automatically the output of programs according to the official Go specs (for example you cannot argue about where brackets should go in Go, because that's apparently fixed by the specs).

On the following page:

```
http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html
```

under the "Formatting" paragraph, it is written that:

> As an example, there's no need to spend time lining up the comments on
>   the fields of a structure. Gofmt will do that for you. Given the
>   declaration

```
type T struct {
    name string // name of the object
    value int // its value
}
```

> gofmt will line up the columns:

```
type T struct {
    name    string // name of the object
    value   int    // its value
}
```

However I don't understand how this could possibly play nice with *diff* and VCSes.

For example, if I had a new line:

```
confuzzabler int // doo doo be doo
```

and run a *diff*, I should get this:

```
2d1
<     confuzzabler int // doo doo be doo
7d5
<
```

And life would be all good: the diff shows the only line that got changed.

However if I re-run the *gofmt* I got this:

```
type T struct {
    confuzzabler int    // doo doo be doo
    name         string // name of the object
    value        int    // its value
}
```

And now I re-run diff and I get this:

```
2,4c2,3
<     confuzzabler int    // doo doo be doo
<     name         string // name of the object
<     value        int    // its value
---
>     name    string // name of the object
>     value   int    // its value
7d5
<
```

Which is a highly confusing and misleading *diff* output because only one line changed.

How do you deal with this as a Go developer?

Comment: Before this get voted as "offtopic" please read the SO FAQ here:

http://stackoverflow.com/faq

which clearly states that SO is the "right place" [sic] to ask questions about programming tools (I have to state this because I recently got a question about a tool downvoted and someone voted to close it... Without of course suggesting anywhere else to post my question).

Comment: I realize this mostly highlights shortcomings of *diff* tools which are too stupid to understand that conceptually both source code are actually exactly the same Go program but I'm still interested to know how I should be dealing with this *gofmt* issue.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: if you read my question carefully you'll see that that's **precisely** the issue I'm describing.  Making a trivial change to the source code, due to the nature of *gofmt*, can make *gofmt* change several lines of code even though you just changed one line (because it's re-aligning **all** your lines, not just the one you added).  This is something that typically drive developers nuts because it produces diffs "for nothing".  Just look at how many people here on SO complain about people doing the kind of alignment that *gofmt* does "because it messes up the diff".

Comment: I think the reasnonig is quite simple there: 1) `gofmt` does reformat code in cases like the one you demonstrated because such is the convention it follows; 2) if it refused to reformat the code in such cases it would break its own rules.  Seems like you want `gofmt` to do its job but not want it to follow its rules to perform that job at the same time.  There is a clear contradiction.

Comment: The objective is to produce good, readable, working code, not to minimize the possible differences between versions of the code.  If you really want to ensure that differences are minimized, place each token of your program on its own line.  Then, when you run diffs, only the changed tokens will show diffs.  But don't ask me to read the code!

Answer (score 6):

```
$ diff --help|grep -i white
  -b  --ignore-space-change  Ignore changes in the amount of white space.
  -w  --ignore-all-space  Ignore all white space.
```

As to issues with VCS, if you were formatting the code yourself following some established convention (let's assume here this convention is what `gofmt` follows) you'd have manually reformatted the whitespace in that code block exactly the way `gofmt` did, and this change would have been counted by any VCS as a change.  So I don't see any problem with semantics in this case, really.  If you instead care about diffing tools provided by VCSes you should probably look whether they do support ignoring whitespace changes as the GNU diff mentioned above does.  FWIW `git diff` does support this with the same `-b` command line option.

Comment: +1 but... What if I do *string a = "kostix "* and then change it to *string a = "kostix  "*  (notice the additional space at the end, from one to two space).  *diff -b* are far from being smart enough to understand the difference between meaningful spaces and non-meaningful ones.  So -1 actually ; )

Comment: Looks like you're more concerned with clicking than with the problem at hand.

Answer (score 5):

Your Go-based project standards should dictate something like:

> Before any Go code is committed to the VCS, it is formatted with `gofmt`.  This is the only acceptable format.

Then there is no argument; if the code passes through `gofmt` unchanged, all is well.  If it changes when passed through `gofmt`, then use the output from `gofmt`.  What you do while editing is up to you (subject to the other coding standards), but this is a requirement for any code checked into your VCS.

Answer (score 1):

If this *really* bothers you, do two checkins.

The first check in adds `confuzzabler`.  A reasonable comment is "Adding new variable to T".
Your diff will be isolated to the code you have actually changed.

Then, perform gofmt.

The second commit is just formatting changes and a reasonable commit msg would be "gofmt".  The diff here will be only code that gofmt has changed.